# How to reference a generic parameter recursively?

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, java-8

I have solved a Y-combinator problem. Just now I found that I cannot reference a generic parameter recursively.

```
Y = λf.(λx.f (x x)) (λx.f (x x))
```

for example:

```
IntUnaryOperator fact = Y(rec -> n -> n == 0 ? 1 : n * rec.applyAsInt(n - 1));

IntUnaryOperator Y(Function<IntUnaryOperator, IntUnaryOperator> f) {
    return g(g -> f.apply(x -> g.apply(g).applyAsInt(x)));
}

IntUnaryOperator g(G g) {
    return g.apply(g);
}

//        v--- I want to remove the middle-interface `G`
interface G extends Function<G, IntUnaryOperator> {/**/}
```

**Q**:  How can I use generic parameter on the method `g` to  avoid introducing an additional interface `G`, and the generic parameter should avoiding the `UNCHECKED` warnings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s not possible. Java doesn’t provide a way to require that a given generic parameter is a functional interface AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a generic method with a recursive type definition

```
<G extends Function<G, IntUnaryOperator>> IntUnaryOperator g(G g) {
    return g.apply(g);
}
```

What doesn’t work, is to invoke this method with a lambda expression, assigning the lambda expression to `G`. [The specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) says

> 15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression
>
> A lambda expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) …

and `G` is not a functional interface, but a type parameter, and there is no way to infer an actual interface type for `G` here.

That still works, when you use the actual interface `G` for the lambda expression:

```
IntUnaryOperator Y(Function<IntUnaryOperator, IntUnaryOperator> f) {
    return g((G)g -> f.apply(x -> g.apply(g).applyAsInt(x)));
}

// renamed the type parameter from G to F to avoid confusion
<F extends Function<F, IntUnaryOperator>> IntUnaryOperator g(F f) {
    return f.apply(f);
}

// can't get rid of this interface
interface G extends Function<G, IntUnaryOperator> {/**/}
```

or

```
IntUnaryOperator fact = Y(rec -> n -> n == 0 ? 1 : n * rec.applyAsInt(n - 1));

IntUnaryOperator Y(Function<IntUnaryOperator, IntUnaryOperator> f) {
    return this.<G>g(g -> f.apply(x -> g.apply(g).applyAsInt(x)));
}

// renamed the type parameter from G to F to avoid confusion
<F extends Function<F, IntUnaryOperator>> IntUnaryOperator g(F f) {
    return f.apply(f);
}

// can't get rid of this interface
interface G extends Function<G, IntUnaryOperator> {/**/}
```

So the method `g` is generic with no dependency to the interface `G`, but the interface is still required to be used as target type for the lambda expression.

Comment: yes, I just found the type variable can be reference recursively too. and the problem is occurs in lambda expression. thanks very much sir. e.g: `g(null)` works fine, but `g(g -> null)` can't work.